# adding new content above a specific content in file

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have following text in a file suppose names as myfile.txt.

```
HWUnit

Configuration
  ConfigInfo
    parm 1
  End ConfigInfo
  ConfigInfo
    EmptyConfig
    ModuleKey     16#0F00
    InAreaSize    0
    OutAreaSize   0
  End ConfigInfo
End Configuration

HWUnitCRC 16#AC7D
End HWUnit
```

I want to add following content above the line containing text "HWUnitCRC" and save the file.

```
NewConfiguration
     param1 value1
End NewConfiguration
```

I have to do this for lot of files and want to write a utility with python3. I am looking for help and template code on how this can be achieved.

Thanks for the help

Comment: That's essentially [inserting a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050848/inserting-characters-in-strings-in-python) into another string at a [certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215728/locate-position-of-string-in-file-python), reading and saving a file is straightforward.

Comment: @Nagev Thanks for hints. Is it possible to share template in python that will help me in moving.

Comment: I'm afraid that's all the help I can offer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
f=open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Stack overflow\myfile.txt','r')
x=f.read()
with open (r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Stack overflow\text.txt','w') as sys.stdout:
    print('NewConfiguration\n    param1 value1\nEnd NewConfiguration\n',x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

PATH = Path() / "myfile.txt"
DELIMITER = "HWUnitCRC 16#AC7D"
NEWLINE = "\n"


def normalize_newlines(content_to_insert):
    """Enforce single leading newline character and two trailing newline
    characters
    """
    newlines = NEWLINE * 2
    content_to_insert = content_to_insert.strip("\n")

    return NEWLINE + content_to_insert + newlines


# using read() will return a string
with myfile.open() as f:
    path_contents = f.read()

# re pattern to match empty string newline character before delimiter string
pattern = re.compile(
    pattern=fr"^$\n(?=^{DELIMITER}$)",
    flags=re.MULTILINE,
)

string_to_insert = """NewConfiguration
     param1 value1
End NewConfiguration
"""

# replace newline character in original path string with new string
new_string = re.sub(
    pattern=pattern,
    repl=normalize_newlines(string_to_insert),
    string=text_from_file,
)

# write new contents to file
with myfile.open("w") as f:
    f.write(new_string)
```

You can also use the [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
from pathlib import Path

PATH = Path() / "myfile.txt"
DELIMITER = "HWUnitCRC 16#AC7D"
NEWLINE = "\n"


def normalize_newlines(content_to_insert):
    """Enforce single leading newline character and two trailing newline
    characters
    """
    newlines = NEWLINE * 2
    content_to_insert = content_to_insert.strip("\n")

    return NEWLINE + content_to_insert + newlines


# using readlines() will return a list
with myfile.open() as f:
    path_contents = f.readlines()

string_to_insert = """NewConfiguration
     param1 value1
End NewConfiguration
"""

# find index of delimiter
idx = path_contents.index(DELIMITER + NEWLINE)

# replace empty string newline character before delimiter string with new string
if path_contents[idx - 1] == NEWLINE:
    path_contents[idx - 1] = normalize_newlines(string_to_insert)

# write new contents to file
with myfile.open("w") as f:
    for line in path_contents:
        f.write(line)
```

Hope that helps.